# Pokemon Go with Google

Tags: pokemon-go

How can I sign in online from a computer to my Pokemon go account if I signed up with Google? I tried using my email and my user name

Comment: you mean to see your pokemon go profile on you pc? you cant

Answer (score 0):

Pokemon Go is a mobile game, and is available on phones and tablets only (iOS and Android, and may not necessarily be optimised for tablet). You cannot access it on your computer, as it requires GPS and location services.

[This page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices) on Niantic's website shows which devices Pokemon Go is supported on.

However, you may be able to see some of your stats and account status on a computer using a third-party service such as [PokeAdvisor](https://pokeadvisor.com/). Services such as this, however, are not official so you should take care before using them.